# How do I fix this "TypeError: string indices must be integers" in my flask login/signup app?

Tags: python, html, json, authentication, flask

I have a problem with my login/signup function. My login function is

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
import os
import json

app = Flask('app')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def intro():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/game', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def game():
    return render_template("game.html")
 
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    path = 'users'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uname = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['psw']
    with open(os.path.join(path, "users.json"), 'r') as myfile:
        data = myfile.read()
    try:
#TypeError: string indices must be integers |/_
        if data["username"] == uname:
            try:
                if data["password"] == password:
                    return render_template("game.html")
                else:
                    return "wrong password"
            except TypeError:
                print("TypeError2")
        else:
            return "wrong username"
    except TypeError:
             print("TypeError")
    
    return render_template("login.html")

@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    uname = ""
    password = ""
    path = 'users'


    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

    else:
        pass


    if request.method == 'POST':
        uname = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['psw']

        with open(os.path.join(path, "users.json"), 'r') as myfile:
            data = myfile.read()
            obj = json.loads(data)

            data = {}
            data["username"] = uname
            data["password"] = password
            

            obj.append(data)

        with open(os.path.join(path, "users.json"), "w") as outfile:
            json.dump(obj, outfile) 
    
            data["password"] = password

            obj.append(data)

        with open(os.path.join(path, "users.json"), "w") as outfile:
            json.dump(obj, outfile) 
    
        return render_template("game.html")

    return render_template("signup.html")
    

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Does this mean my username has to be numbers only? And how can I change this?

I get my data from a .json file, then read/write it. I am suspecting I should have something instead of an 'if statement', and possibly remove it altogether.

## **EDITED QUESTION**

Comment: Looks like you forgot to decode the JSON file contents: `data = json.loads(myfile.read())`

Comment: @Woodford at scruffyboy13 at not_speshal I didn't put the full code for some time saving, sorry, my code is updated.

Comment: @scruffyboy13 I didn't put the full code for some time saving, sorry, my code is updated.

Comment: @not_speshal I didn't put the full code for some time saving, sorry, my code is updated.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're reading `users.json`, your `data` variable is a string.

You're trying to get a dictionary, so you should be using the `json` module to read the file like so:

```
import json
data = json.loads(open("users.json").read())
```

Answer (score 1):

So you're getting the error because you're trying to read the file with normal python instead of using the json library.

to get the data from a json file, your code should look something like this:

```
import json

with open(os.path.join(path, "users.json"), "r") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

This makes the variable data a dictionary which you can then access using like you do, `data["username"]` or `data.get("username")`.

If you use `data.get("username")` it will supress an error (and return None) if "username" doesn't exist whereas `data["username"]` will raise an error if "username" doesn't exist.